# Is film making not based on any islamic message but a social message in general times allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith

I am studying film and television. I have seen that promoting Islam is acceptable but what if my message is more of a social message, or my film is an art film and totally abstract in nature. What if I decide on approaching genres other than romance or social ones like horror, Sci-fi or suspense thrillers. Will that be appropriate.

Comment: You are seeking for issuing a fatwa or an opinion based answer. This site does not support either.

Comment: How so is this question opinion-based? The OP'er asked if he is allowed to make movies that hasn't got a direct link with islam and is more culturally influenced.

Comment: Please provide examples on how this "social message" differs from an Islamic message.